# PHD/Master/Bachelor Thesis: Which Document Class to Choose

Tags: memoir, koma-script, document-classes, classicthesis, thesis

As I already mentioned in my [previous question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/290427/best-practice-package-for-mathematical-documents-amsmath-and-beyond), I intend to give a LaTeX introduction to phd students. Most of them will already be using LaTeX somehow but their knowledge will be random. I want to give them a systematic approach. In addition I want to show them the best practice for common problems/tasks.

> The (German) **[slides](https://manuelkuehner.files.wordpress.com/2015/04/kurs-folien_2011-11-17.pdf)** I use were created in 2011 (not important for the question though). There is also a **[handout](https://manuelkuehner.files.wordpress.com/2015/04/kurs-handout_2011-11-17.pdf)**
> (same content but different formatting).

In order to reduce complexity I only use the standard document class `article` in the examples but I want to give them an advice for the appropriate document class for their thesis.

**Question [Edit]: What are the advantages and disadvantages of the most common document classes for a thesis? What is there to consider?**

## 1 My Thoughts so Far

### 1.1 Book Class from KOMA-Script (`scr­book`)

I used the book class from [KOMA-Script](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/koma-script) in my thesis ([here's the template on Blogoverflow](http://tex.blogoverflow.com/2015/01/latex-thesis-template-manuel-kuehner/)).

- (+) German documentation (important for some).
- (+) Good documentation.
- (-) I think that there are not so many  KOMA-Script related questions questions here on this site.
- (-) The developer is not very active ob this site as far as I know.
- (+) Just one "package" (the document class) instead of many packages for common problems. This means less problems with compatibility among different packages.
- (-) On the other site sometimes it's easier to have one package for one problem (easier documentation).
- (+) Active development (last version on CTAN from 2021).
- (+) Dedicated project website (http://www.komascript.de/).

### 1.2 Memoir Class (`memoir`)

I have never used the [memoir class](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/memoir) but I have read often about it here on this site.

- (+) Many questions here on this site.
- (+) Good documentation.
- (+) Active development (last version on CTAN from 2021-06-16).

### 1.3 Standard Book Class (`book`)

- (+) Many questions here on this site.
- (-) Maybe not so many options as for the other two document classes (KOMA-Script and memoir).

## 2 Your Thoughts?

- Maybe you can point out some (+) and (-) like compatibility with the most important packages like [tikz/pgf](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf), [geometry](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/geometry), [float](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/float), [hyperref](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) and so on.
- What else do you think are important aspects?

## 3 Additional Thoughts

- I am not sure if I should add the package [classicthesis](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/classicthesis) to the list.

## 4 Similar Questions

- [What are the strengths and weaknesses of KOMA-Script and memoir?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7742/what-are-the-strengths-and-weaknesses-of-koma-script-and-memoir)
- [Which package is best/easiest for a TeX newbie to lay out a book for print?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/51147/which-package-is-best-easiest-for-a-tex-newbie-to-lay-out-a-book-for-print)
- [What about ClassicThesis?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/291459/what-about-classicthesis)
- [Which packages should I recommend to postgraduates in different academic disciplines?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/237100/which-packages-should-i-recommend-to-postgraduates-in-different-academic-discipl/)
- [Best Practice (Packages) for a Standard Technical Article With Math and Figures](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/232007/best-practice-packages-for-a-standard-technical-article-with-math-and-figures)

Comment: The problem is that `best` is not an applicable adjective here. That's why everybody has an opinion. Convenient, least hassle, modular etc are the ones that might be relevant. `memoir`  is amazing but I won't touch it again. Same with KOMA

Comment: The best answer is "It depends". Every document class is good for a certain task or it can be useful in more situations, so the choice ultimately *depends* on which one is more suitable for your case, and which one you prefer. But asking for opinions is not an appropriate format for this site because of its inherent organization.

Comment: @percusse Yes of course. I just want to collect your thoughts and I think the question is easier to find in Google if I oversimplify the title/question/subject. If that's a problem I can choose a less polarizing title/question.

Comment: @Alenanno: I updated the question. Is that ok now? I am sure you know what I mean. If you prefer a specific way to describe it then I am open for proposals.

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner: Keep it simple -- I am still very fond of using the traditional (i.e. standard) LaTeX classes. There's a bunch of good packages that extend the features of them. I used KOMA classes for a while but I found configuration not well done (my personal point of view, as well as the documentation not really convincing). For `memoir`: The emulation features seems to be nice but is not always really convenient

Comment: `scrbook` is not just a class like `book`. KOMA- script is a bundle of different packages and `scrbook` loads quite a bunch of them. `scrbase` for the most simple definitions, `tocbasic` to set up floats and their lists, `typearea` to control the page margins (and more). `scrlayer-scrpage` would be the choice if you want to change page headers and footers.

Comment: In my point of view, the standard classes are so simple, that their appearance and maybe functionality are easy to change, for example `titlesec` for customization of the appearance of structural commands. Many packages are made for that. KOMA and memoir implement parts of that functionality themselves, meaning you can make easy changes *within* the predefined range. If you want to have something not included, it gets hacky pretty soon. Or a clean solution would be outright impossible to find for an inexperienced user.

Comment: @Johannes_B Thanks - good points. That's also my experience but I don't have enough background knowledge too know whether it is me or the classes :)

Comment: A few LaTeX users have discussed *best-practice* within the last few months. As there is that variety in doing stuff, *who* decides what best practice is and what makes its way into a presentation/tutorial/wikibook? Some advice on that, some on that, some write some bad hacks and outdated stuff on some block, leaving a beginner lost within a flood of **trustworthy?** information. This is a pretty bad situation.

Comment: @Johannes_B I agree. Therefore I will bring a bunch of books to the introduction because I think it's better to start with a book (one main source of information). I only recommend recent books which ideally cover pgf and biblatex.

Comment: Bring some books made with Word and some made with TeX and ask the students which one they prefer. If they prefer the Word ones, ... well, they should stick with it and nice typesetting ...

Comment: @Johannes_B Maybe there is a misunderstanding. I do not want to convince people to use LaTeX. Anyway - I will delete the question since it causes negative attention which I did not intend at all.

Comment: No negative atention at all (from my side). Just my concerns regarding the current situation of documentation of LaTeX. Drop iin the chat if you want to discuss this :-)

Comment: Try this template: https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/doriens-phd-thesis-template/ntgfsykpsrwb#.WZ-f74oRVTY

Comment: Oh please, don't follow this link. It is a trap.